# How to stop function being called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out why my code is triggering multiple calls of a function. I'm creating a calendar app and each time I delete an event, it increments the number of times the function gets called. It must be something to do with the for loop which I've tried to resolve using 'break' but doesn't work.

When the user opens a day in the calendar, it displays the events. I have an event listener to trigger a modal of "Are you sure you want to delete event?".

```
// Delete event
delEvent = document.getElementsByClassName('eventEntry');
for (var e = 0; e < delEvent.length; e++) {
    delEvent[e].addEventListener('click', delete_event,false);
    break;
}
// Opens model to prompt event delete
function delete_event(d){
    id = d.currentTarget.id;
    $('#modal-delete').modal('open');
    delModalBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('delTrue');
    for (var i = 0; i < delModalBtn.length; i++) {
        delModalBtn[i].addEventListener('click', event_del_true,false);
        break;
    }
}
```

When the user confirms they want to delete the event, **event_del_true** function is called (code below). This technically works but the Toast popup component from MaterializeCSS displays multiple times.

For example:

- Delete 1 event = event is deleted and popup is displayed.
- Delete a 2nd event = the event is deleted but the popup displays twice, and so the cycle begins

  ```
   function event_del_true(){
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "php/delete-event.php",
       data: {id: id}
   }).done(function() {
       M.toast({
           html: 'Event deleted',
           classes: 'rounded',
           displayLength: 2000,
           inDuration: 375,
           outDuration: 300
       });
   });
  ```

Any help would greatly be appreciated, Kind Regards.

Comment: Every time you delete an element you add another click listener to all the `delTrue` elements. It's almost always wrong to add event listeners inside other listeners.

Comment: *to trigger a modal* .. **a** modal - you have one modal, but every time you show it you add a new `event_del_true` event handler.   Move your 5 lines that add `event_del_true` outside the `delete_event` method (as you do with the first 5 lines to setup the delete_event event

Comment: Avoid mixing longhand JavaScript with jQuery. If you're using jQuery, then **use** jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to add a loop here if you break the loop in the first iteration?

```
for (var i = 0; i < delModalBtn.length; i++) {
    delModalBtn[i].addEventListener('click', event_del_true,false);
    break;
}
```

Plus, every time you trigger the function, you are adding another event listener to the button, so the effect `event_del_true` will be added on top of each other every time you call `delete_event`

a simple fix would be moving this line out of the function

```
// Opens model to prompt event delete
function delete_event(d){
    id = d.currentTarget.id;
    $('#modal-delete').modal('open');
}

// add the event to every button with the class ONCE only
delModalBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('delTrue');
for (var i = 0; i < delModalBtn.length; i++) {
    delModalBtn[i].addEventListener('click', event_del_true,false);
}
```

Comment: You're right, I was using the loop in an unnecessary place so have done what you have suggested. Unfortunately the issue still remains.